# How to call birt report from jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, birt

I have generated jasper report using birt tool.. it is working fine from birt report viewer.. But now I want to run birt report from jsp page. So say any user clicks on submit button, that birt report should be run.

As i am new to jasper report, I don't have any idea about this.. Please help me.

Comment: `I have generated jasper report using birt tool` - How it can be?

Answer (score 0):

**Add this tag in your web.xml file**

```
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/birt.tld /taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld /taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

**use this tag libry in your jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld" prefix="birt"%>
```

**Add this code where you want in jsp**

```
<birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="bank_detail_report.rptdesign" pattern="run" height="600" width="1000" format="pdf" scrolling="yes" showParameterPage="false">
    <birt:param name="param1" value='<%=request.getParameter("txtParam1")%>'></birt:param>
    <birt:param name="param2" value='<%=request.getParameter("txtParam1")%>'></birt:param>
</birt:viewer>
```